# XOR operation for char array in java

Tags: java

```
    char td[] = {'1','0','0','1','1','1'};
    char s_td[] = new char[td.length];

    for(int i=0; i<td.length; i++)
    {
        if(i==0)
            s_td[i] = (char) (td[td.length-1] ^ td[i]);
        else
            s_td[i] = (char)(s_td[i-1] ^ td[i]);
    }
for(int i=0 ; i<s_td.length ; i++)
        System.out.print(s_td[i]);
```

For the given code snippet, I need `s_td[] = {0,0,0,1,0,1}`, i.e. simple XOR operation.
Instead, I am getting `{ ,0, ,1, ,1}`. As you can see it is working correctly for even positions but giving blank space in odd positions. I tried casting it to **int** which gives `{0,48,0,49,0,49}` while using **Character.getNumericValue(s_td[i])** gives `{-1,0,-1,1,-1,1}`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's unclear what your aim is here but note: 1) bit twiddling on character codes rarely makes sense and may not result in a valid character code; 2) bit twiddling on a byte might make more sense but is a signed value so printing it out in hexadecimal or binary would make it easier to understand.

Comment: The aim is to perform XOR operation for elements of char td[]. The first element should be XORed with the last one to obtain the first element of the resulting array. For others, they must be XORed with the immediate next element to obtain the corresponding elements of the resulting array. For eg. XOR operation of {'1','0','0','1','1','1'} must result in {0,0,0,1,0,1}

Answer (score 0):

**[XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate)** is working as expected. Since you are applying it to chars which get promoted to int(ASCII value for that character) in java.

```
1 ^ 1 = 0 [ Thats how XOR works]
```

Also, it should be noted that they there are bitwise operators and are executed on the binary equivalents only. Would recommend you to go through the truth table as well.

Now in your case, It is all about the matter of casting the value back to the character from int after doing an operation. That's why your output is varying

Answer (score 0):

From the description in the comment, I think instead of

```
s_td[i] = (char)(s_td[i-1] ^ td[i]);
```

you meant

```
s_td[i] = (char)(td[i-1] ^ td[i]);
```

However, my original comment still applies. You are bit twiddling with a text datatype. That's fine: the result is an integer. But, you are casting it back to a text datatype. For your data, that's going to result in non-printable characters, at the least.